# Logstash output to ssl elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ssl, apache-kafka, logstash

I am getting data from a kafka topic through logstash and want to connect to an SSL-protected elasticsearch(all these are in docker images). I have tested the connection with a non SSL-elasticsearch and it worked fine, but with the ssl-elastic does not.
Do you have any suggestions,
e.g do i have to change my logstash configuration output to connect to https://elasticsearch:9200,
Do i have to install x-pack in my logstash,
Any suggestions

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your current Logstash output configuration?

Comment: Could you explain what it's the error in log?

Comment: output {
 elasticsearch {
  hosts => "https://elasticsearch:9200"
                index => "xxxx"
                workers => 1
                user => "****"
         password => "*****"
         ecs_compatibility => disabled
        
 }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }

}

Comment: In the above configuration i have tried also ssl=>true, ssl_verification=> false, but without any result. Also, the logs are "that i tried to connect to dead instance". Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you try to put this params in your logstash at the elsaticseach output level :          ilm_enabled=>false

Comment: okokok. thank you. i will try it. what i achieve with this? the problem is on my configuration file only?

Comment: You need to provide more context about how the call is being made - what language are you making the call in, what libraries are using for the call, etc.  In AWS, there are many things that can make an HTTP call not work - you need to tell us what you are using.

Comment: hello! thanks for your reply! I am using docker images for Wazuh, opendistro for elasticsearch, kibana, nginx. The docker images are: wazuh/wazuh-odfe:4.0.3_1.11.0, amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.11.0, wazuh/wazuh-kibana-odfe:4.0.3_1.11.0 and for logstash an OSS image 10.1. I am making the call in the logstash configuration file as Kafka input and an elasticsearch output. I have successfully connected without ssl in the wazuh, kibana, elastic, but with ssl i have a problem logstash with the ssl elastic. If you need any extra information please let me know! Thank you in advance!

Comment: @JoS. Check out this link -> https://www.elastic.co/blog/configuring-ssl-tls-and-https-to-secure-elasticsearch-kibana-beats-and-logstash. Although this is for Elastic's docker distribution, I would assume the way you configure transport security in Kibana, Elasticsearch and Logstash will not change for Wazuh's and Amazon's distribution.